# jquery update property in an array from another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to update a property in an array from another array by matching a field by using jquery.

```
objArray = [ { Id: 1, Val: 'A'}, { Id: 3, Val: 'B'}, { Id: 5, Val: 'C'} ];
```

After doing some processing, I am getting an array like this.

```
objnewArray = [ { Id: 1, Value: 'AA'}, { Id: 3, Value: 'BB'}, { Id: 5, Value: 'CC'} ];
```

Now I want to update objArray Val field to objnewArray's value field so the result is like this

```
 objArray = [ { Id: 1, Val: 'AA'}, { Id: 3, Val: 'BB'}, { Id: 5, Val: 'CC'} ];
```

Is there any other way other than looping both the arrays ,matching the Id and updating the Val property?

Comment: `objArray = objnewArray`

Comment: Can you show us how are you creating `objnewArray` array?

Comment: Both are different objects with different properties. For simplicity I just mentioned two properties.

Comment: @DotNetLearner please share code that process original array

Comment: @DotNetLearner In my understanding, you should parse it along with your current processing. You can try something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twjkd72d/)

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. What am trying to do is update one property in an array from another array based on a matching key. I am able to achieve it with hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table and loop the target first and the the new object for assigning to the old object.

```js
var objArray = [{ Id: 1, Val: 'A' }, { Id: 3, Val: 'B' }, { Id: 5, Val: 'C' }],
    objnewArray = [{ Id: 1, Value: 'AA', extra: 42 }, { Id: 3, Value: 'BB' }, { Id: 5, Value: 'CC' }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

objArray.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.id] = a;
});

objnewArray.forEach(function (a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        hash[a.id][k] = a[k];
    });
});

console.log(objnewArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var objArray = [{ Id: 1, Val: 'A' }, { Id: 3, Val: 'B' }, { Id: 5, Val: 'C' }],
    objnewArray = [{ Id: 1, Value: 'AA', extra: 42 }, { Id: 3, Value: 'BB' }, { Id: 5, Value: 'CC' }],
    hash = new Map;

objArray.forEach(a => hash.set(a.id, a));
objnewArray.forEach(a => Object.keys(a).forEach(k => hash.get(a.id)[k] = a[k]));

console.log(objnewArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var objArray = [{ Id: 1, Val: 'A' }, { Id: 3, Val: 'B' }, { Id: 5, Val: 'C' }],
    objnewArray = [{ Id: 1, Value: 'AA', extra: 42 }, { Id: 3, Value: 'BB' }, { Id: 5, Value: 'CC' }];

objnewArray.forEach(a =>
    Object.keys(a).forEach(k => objArray.find(b => a.id === b.id)[k] = a[k]));

console.log(objnewArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the array, create new key and assign its value properly, delete the old key. You are done.

```js
objnewArray = [ { Id: 1, Value: 'AA'}, { Id: 3, Value: 'BB'}, { Id: 5, Value: 'CC'} ];


var objArray = objnewArray.map(function(el){
   el.Val = el.Value; // Create new key Val
   delete el.Value; // Delete old key Value
   return el;
});

console.log(objArray);
```

Comment: This deletes the Value property from the second array and adds a new property.Right? My original arrays are entirely two different sets with different properties, just with the key as Id

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over objArray and $.extend the object

Jquery -

```js
objArray = [ { Id: 1, Value: 'A'}, { Id: 3, Value: 'B'}, { Id: 5, Value: 'C'} ];
objnewArray = [ { Id: 1, Value: 'AA'}, { Id: 3, Value: 'BB'}, { Id: 5, Value: 'CC'} ];

objArrayById = [];

objArray.forEach(function(value){
  objArrayById[value.Id] = value;
});

objnewArray.forEach(function(value,index){
  objArrayById[value.Id] = $.extend(objArrayById[value.Id],value);
});

console.log(objArrayById);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

ES6

```js
objArray = [ { Id: 1, Value: 'A'}, { Id: 3, Value: 'B'}, { Id: 5, Value: 'C'} ];
objnewArray = [ { Id: 1, Value: 'AA'}, { Id: 3, Value: 'BB'}, { Id: 5, Value: 'CC'} ];

objArrayById = [];

objArray.forEach(function(value){
  objArrayById[value.Id] = value;
});

objnewArray.forEach(function(value){
  objArrayById[value.Id] = Object.assign(objArrayById[value.Id],value);
});

console.log(objArrayById);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` with a `hash table` and `Object.assign` to create a shallow object copy to get the required output array - see demo below:

```js
var objArray = [ { Id: 1, Val: 'A'}, { Id: 3, Val: 'B'}, { Id: 5, Val: 'C'} ];
var objnewArray = [ { Id: 1, Value: 'AA'}, { Id: 3, Value: 'BB'}, { Id: 5, Value: 'CC'}];
                   
var result = objArray.reduce(function(hash){
  
  //create hash table
  objnewArray.forEach(function(element){
     hash[element.Id]=element.Value;
  });
  
  // reduce to the required result
  return function(prev, curr){
    var element = Object.assign({}, curr); 
    element.Val = hash[curr.Id];
    prev.push(element);
    return prev;
  }
}(Object.create(null)),[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: @DotNetLearner let me know (and vote up too!) if this answer helped you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar to @void answer
Iterating through `objArray` so not to update the `objnewArray` object

```js
var objnewArray = [ { Id: 1, Value: 'AA'}, { Id: 3, Value: 'BB'}, { Id: 5, Value: 'CC'} ];

var objArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objnewArray));

//console.log(objArray)
objArray = objArray.map(function(doc){
  doc.Val = doc.Value;
  delete doc.Value;
  return doc;
});

console.log(objArray)
```